# Xl.Read.File function doesn't read all the rows

Tags: r, excel, excel-2003

I have an file saved with Excel Worksheet 2003 and I tried to read in R.
No package or function worked, only `XL.Read.file` from excel.link package.
The problem is that the function read only the maximum no from the excel (1048575).

```
library(excel.link)
df = xl.read.file('Date.xls',header=TRUE,xl.sheet='Date')
```

Anybody knows where is the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone looking, try adding the two arguments:

- `top.left.cell` = the first cell of your table on the header row
- `xl.sheet` = the name of the sheet you want to read

```
#example 
library(excel.link)
df <- xl.read.file('Date.xls', header=TRUE, xl.sheet='Date', top.left.cell = "A1", xl.sheet = 'sheet name')
```